# How to use python to highlight text in an image?

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to complete a task which asks me to highlight text from an image by using robot framework combine with python script, but I have no idea on how to do it. Can someone help me with this? The issue is how can I highlight some specific text in the image but not highlighting whole text in the image.

I did try to figure it out with python script and robot framework, but mine isn't really working, so I wish someone could help me. My python script highlighted the whole text in the image, how should I do to let it only highlight the string 'HS. CODE: 9408. 50'? But since everytime I process the script, the string should be different everytime for different image, but now let's say we want only HS. CODE: 9408. 50 to be highlighted.
[This is the ss after running the python script, as you can see the whole text are being highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLcDf.png)

#The below will be my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# Load the image and convert it to grayscale
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/rmyeow/Desktop/Example pic/sample.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the image to make the text stand out
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find the text in the image
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(thresh)

# Draw a yellow semi-transparent rectangle around each character
for box in boxes.splitlines():
    box = box.split(" ")
    x, y, w, h = int(box[1]), int(box[2]), int(box[3]), int(box[4])
    alpha = 0.3
    overlay = img.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(overlay, (x, img.shape[0]-y), (w, img.shape[0]-h), (0, 255, 255), -1)
    img = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, img, 1 - alpha, 0)

# Show the result
cv2.imshow("Highlighted Text", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What code are you currently trying? In what way isn't it working? Please be specific and include all relevant code and messages (warnings, errors, etc.).

Comment: @SolomonUcko I did upload my python code, pls have a look~

Comment: Yep, thanks. I've added an answer to explain what you can add/change to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score -1):

In order to determine where that text is, use `image_to_data`, described at https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/, to get output in TSV (Tab Separated Values format), described at https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Command-Line-Usage.html#tsv-output.

I'd recommend either using the `DATAFRAME` output format with the `pandas` package, or using the `DICT` format and manually keeping track of indices. You can use the `STRING` format and parse the TSV yourself if you want, but you don't need to.

Once you have the data, split your input into words, find where those words occur consecutively in the data, and use the corresponding boxes (or perhaps the bounding box around them).

Feel free to add a comment, edit your question, or post a new question, if you've tried this and get stuck. If you post a new question, please add links in both directions. Please post your new code and explain what output you got vs what you expected, as you did a good job with here in your first edit.

You can try something like this:

```py
def sliding_window(iterable, n):  # from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    # sliding_window('ABCDEFG', 4) --> ABCD BCDE CDEF DEFG
    it = iter(iterable)
    window = collections.deque(islice(it, n), maxlen=n)
    if len(window) == n:
        yield tuple(window)
    for x in it:
        window.append(x)
        yield tuple(window)

target = 'HS. CODE: 9408. 50'
target_words = tuple(target.split())

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(thresh)

left = top = bottom = right = None

for i, words in sliding_window(data['text']):
    if words == target_words:
        left = min(map(int, data['left']))
        top = min(map(int, data['top']))
        right = max(int(l) + int(w) for l, w in zip(data['left'], data['width']))
        bottom = max(int(t) + int(h) for t, h in zip(data['top'], data['height']))
        # draw a rectangle with sides at left, top, right, and bottom
        break
```

Comment: Thanks Ucko, but can u write me the code instead?

Comment: @SooHana I've added some code to my answer, though I haven't tested it.